# Accessing SQL Report Web Services

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, coldfusion

I am testing an app locally that is built in ColdFusion. I have SQL Report Services running and I would like to access reports using ColdFusion.

I can only access web services through IE. How can I enable anonymous access to the server so that I could do a simple HTTP request from within ColdFusion to grab the report?

Secondly, is there a better way to do this than what I am thinking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anonymous access to Reporting Services isn't recommended, although if you're controlling all the access to the reports through a CF layer, then it should be okay. Just go to the web server hosting RS and tell the website that it should use Anonymous access, running as a particular user (to whom you then grant sufficient permission to access the reports). Saving Data Source credentials would also be worth doing in this environment.

Then, you should be able to use the Web Services layer with the Render command to pull down the HTML for a particular report.

Hope this helps,

Rob

Comment: Rob,

Thanks for the response. I am hosting the server locally for now, until i get all this stuff figured out. Do you have a link to the instructions on how to make it anonymous?

I've been searching but coming up blank.

Comment: In Windows, go to the Administrative Tools and find the IIS Admin section. Find the website you're using for SSRS, and edit its properties. You should see a Security tab, and in there, a button which opens a dialog for how people authenticate against it. If you tick the "Allow Anonymous Access" option and nominate a user, then people will access SSRS that way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an excellent article to access reporting services from Java. May be this post will be helpful for others, if not you.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/christophputz/archive/2010/05/07/accessing-ms-reporting-services-with-java.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage